# Character in each alternate index of S1 should be replaced with S2 using java

Tags: java

For example i have a string s1 = "java" and alternate character of index s1 should be replaced with string s2 ="va". that is final result should be jvavva. I was able to do by using a specific letter. But I'm unable to do when i have a string such as "example"

```
    for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
        ch = s1.charAt(i);
        replace = s1.replace("A", s2);
    }       
    System.out.println(replace);
```

Comment: Why do you have `ch` if you are not using it?

Comment: I'm new to java, was trying to do in different ways. actually for above code for loop is also not required I guess

Answer (score 0):

So, do you want to replace a character or a string inside an another string to something else?

Something like this:

```
    String text = "example";
    String replaceable = "a";
    String substitute = "va";

    text text.replaceAll(replaceable, substitute);

    System.out.println(text);
```

**Edited:**

```
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String origin = "example";
    String substitute = "va";
    for(int i=0; i<origin.length(); i++){
        char ch = origin.charAt(i);
        result.append((i%2 == 0) ? ch : substitute);
    }
```

That replaces every other character with 'va'.

Comment: I wanted to replace alternate char in a string, that is x, m, l and result should be evaavapvae

Answer (score 0):

Do bot replace anything, just build a new string.

Using your variables you need something like this:

```
String replace="";
for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
    ch = s1.charAt(i);
    if (i%2) == 0 {
        replace += ch;
     } else {
        replace += s2; 
     }
}       
System.out.println(replace);
```

It would've been better to use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) for concatenation, but you probably have not learned this class yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to do using StringBuilder